# How to suppress Maven compiler warnings in Jenkins

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I use [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) to compile the project. With current configuration when project is building I get the `WARNING` in the log. My requirement is that how can I suppress the warnings when project build. Please let me know.

**POM configuration**

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.1</version>
  <configuration>
  <source>1.7</source>
  <target>1.7</target>
  <failOnError>false</failOnError>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: could you please also share an example of warning you would like to hide?

Comment: @ A. Di Matteo i want to hide the all warnings from the log.

Comment: @A. Di Matteo it shows me unused imports as warning.if i suppress this would be nice.

Comment: you don't get such a warning normally by the maven-compiler-plugin. Are you using any other plugin in addition? Please share part of the build, from the `[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin` on till the concerned warning

Comment: @A. Di Matteo Thank you for your quick replies.yes i also use `xtend-maven-plugin` seems like problem with there.

Answer (score 2):

See [javac - Java programming language compiler, Options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options):

> An additional set of non-standard options are specific to the current virtual machine and compiler implementations and are subject to change in the future. Non-standard options begin with **-X**.
>
> ...
>
> **-Xlint:none**   Disable all warnings.

See also [How to get compiler warnings when building a Jenkins plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770278/how-to-get-compiler-warnings-when-building-a-jenkins-plugin):

```
  <configuration>
    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:none</compilerArgument>
```